# Get selected app from flutter share plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, share

I am using the [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) plugin in my flutter app.

My use case is as follows:
If the user selects WhatsApp from the app list, then I want to share a predefined message template with the URL.
If the user selects any other social media app like FB/Twitter/Instagram/etc, then it should just forward the URL.

The issue over here is that I am unable to get any information on which app was selected from the share dialog.

Any help would be appreciated!